# Nessus Security Vulnability Fix: SSL Version 2 (v2) Protocol Detection

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7, tls, nessus

Below, in quotes, is a medium severity issue discovered after scanning an IIS web server, with a tool called Nessus.

"Consult the application's documentation to disable SSL 2.0 and use
SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0, or higher instead"

I found this article, but I cannot find the "Server" folder.  "Client" is the only folder listed on the machine I had scanned, under this registry path, `HKey_Local_Machine \System\ CurrentControlSet\ Control\ SecurityProviders\ SCHANNEL\ Protocols\ PCT 1.0\`.  The OS is Windows Server 2008, x64.  What steps do I need to take to fix this vulnerability?

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=187498

Does this have to be set a certain way?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\
```

...create a key for `SSL 2.0`, if it doesn't exist.  Then inside that key, create a key for `Server` if it doesn't exist.

Then inside that key (you should be at `SCHANNEL\Protocols\SSL 2.0\Server`), create a DWORD value with the name of `Enabled` and a value of `0`.

Once that's in place, reboot the server - a service restart alone isn't enough for this change to take effect.

Comment: If I don't have a "Server" folder under "SSL 2.0", should I just create the folder?

Comment: @MacGyver Yes, create it if it doesn't exist (the folders are called keys in the registry).

Answer (score 0):

I've used [IISCrypto](https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Default.aspx) to fix it for me.